# Erro PHP-CGI Hospedagem Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, hospedagem

Fiz uma pergunta anteriormente sobre instalar o Laravel em Hospedagem Windows, por causa do arquivo **web.config**.

Consegui fazer com que o site rodasse. Consegui fazer o arquivo e colocar na pasta **public** do site. Só não sei se ele está seguindo totalmente as regras do arquivo **.htaccess** que o próprio Laravel monta. Vou postar o código do arquivo lá embaixo depois.

Porque agora acontece o seguinte: quando abro o site, demora um pouco mais que o normal. E quando clico em outro LINK aparece uma página com esse erro:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> C:\PHP_5.5\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Mas se eu atualizo a página, abre.

Se eu vou pra outra página, acontece o mesmo. E as vezes não acontece. Testei em vários computadores, está do mesmo jeito.

O que pode ser ?

Segue o arquivo **web.config**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
      <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
        <clear />
        <add name="php-5.5" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP_5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Vc ta usando IIS7?

Comment: Não é eu, meu caro. É a hospedagem Locaweb. Mas deve ser IIS7 sim.

Comment: Tente ver com o provedor se vc tem acesso ao gerencialmento do seu site. Vc pode instalar fast gci através do Web Installer. O fast cgi disponibiliza várias opções para vc gerenciar seu php sem ter que colocar nada no web.config. Essa é a melhor maneira pois configurando tudo na mão podemos esquecer algo. Só uma nota. EU acho que IIS não lê .htacces. SOmente webconfig.

Comment: Você tem como configurar o log de erros no PHP.INI (se a hospedagem lhe limitar)? Geralmente erro 500 é exibido em modo de produção, ao invés de mostrar o erro do arquivo PHP, pode ser alguma informação que o Laravel tenta gravar ou ler na pasta "storage" que esta inacessível...

Comment: ...Se não souber como configurar, procure no php.ini uma linha que contenha algo como `error_log=`, e adicione um caminho como `error_log=C:/Documents/peter/error_php.log`, se já estiver setado então procure o caminho do log. Note que se tiver assim `;error_log=` o log não irá funcionar, então remova o `;` e reinicie o IIS (acredito que o IIS não necessite ser "reiniciado").